# Different WSDL after creating the web service from a WSDL

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a wsdl and can create the server from it in various ways. But I need the wsdl generated by the web service is just like the original wsdl.

I have the .wsdl file and generate the .asmx file (for example using the wsdl.exe)

When caught the URL localhost/MyWS.asmx?wsdl the wsdl generated is not equal to the source.

It is possible that the wsdl is equal after the generated webservice?